# Все пропадает при активации шейдера

Tags: c#, opengl, шейдеры

В написании шейдеров я ещё новичок - изучил на треть "[Трёхмерная графика и язык программирования шейдеров](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNnoP3v5fUAhXCJJoKHSf8BC8QFghPMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsa2systems.ru%2Fsvn%2Fpublic%2Fsa2bok%2F00%2520-%2520IT%2F09%2520-%2520%25D0%259A%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BF%25D1%258C%25D1%258E%25D1%2582%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2584%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%2FOpenGL%2F%25D0%25A0%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%2520-%2520OpenGL%2520%25D0%25A2%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D1%2585%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F%2520%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2584%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%2520%25D0%25B8%2520%25D1%258F%25D0%25B7%25D1%258B%25D0%25BA%2520%25D0%25BF%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B8%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2520%25D1%2588%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B9%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%2520(2005).pdf&usg=AFQjCNE4FLRRKMTvU7fIhVbgbZaxJKeh8w&sig2=-D_qDK5lDmQlmrHHhVgYBA&cad=rjt)" и недавно попытался реализовать шаблон для вершинного шейдера, возвращающий исходные данные, а уже на его основе создавать выполняющие полезную работу (например, освещение). Фрагментный же шейдер я решил уже научить простым изменением, вроде изменения цветового баланса всех пикселей. Я начал с того, что прописал простые классы для вершинного и фрагментного шейдера соотвественно:

```
public class VertexShader
{
    private int id;
    public int ID { get { return id; } }
    public VertexShader(string[] code)
    {
        id = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB);
        glShaderSourceARB(id, 1, code, IntPtr.Zero);
        glCompileShaderARB(id);

        int complete;
        glGetObjectParameterivARB(id, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, out complete);
        if (complete == GL_FALSE)
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

public class FragmentShader
{
    private int id;
    public int ID { get { return id; } }
    public FragmentShader(string[] code)
    {
        id = glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);
        glShaderSourceARB(id, 1, code, IntPtr.Zero);
        glCompileShaderARB(id);

        int complete;
        glGetObjectParameterivARB(id, GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB, out complete);
        if (complete == GL_FALSE)
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Я насторожился уже на этом этапе: даже при грубом нарушении синтаксиса (в данном случае я попробовал убрать функцию `main()`) компилятор никаких ошибок не выдаёт (учтите, я пытался проследить ошибки и с помощью исключений, а не закрытия приложения).

Далее я написал класс для программы:

```
public class ShaderProgram
{
    private int id;
    public int ID { get { return id; } }
    public ShaderProgram(VertexShader vertshader, FragmentShader fragshader)
    {
        id = glCreateProgramObjectARB();

        glAttachObjectARB(id, vertshader.ID);
        glAttachObjectARB(id, fragshader.ID);

        glLinkProgramARB(id);

        int complete;
        glGetObjectParameterivARB(id, GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB, out complete);
        if (complete == GL_FALSE)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

При активации этой программы функцией `glUseProgramObjectARB()` все полигоны начисто пропадают. Скорее всего, дело в коде, несмотря на то, что я пытался донельзя его упростить, и пробовал копипастить из разных источников.

Вот мой код для шейдеров:

```
Вершинный:

#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPoc;
void main() {
gl_Position.xyz = vertexPos;
gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}

Фрагментный:

#version 330
out vec4 color;
void main() {
color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Список мер, которые я пробовал:

- Отключать один из двух шейдеров - работает точно так же;
- Менять задний фон. Пробовал белый, чёрный, и рекомендуемый васильковый цвет, всё так же - ничего не видно, кроме собственно цвета фона.
- Лог компиляции\линкования всегда пустой. Читал, что вроде так и должно быть в некоторых случаях при успешной компиляции…
- Статус компиляции\линкования получаю через `glGetObjectParameterivARB()` (константы `GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB` и `GL_OBJECT_LINK_STATUS_ARB` соотвественно). Во всех случаях возвращает единицу (`GL_TRUE`).

Используемый мной враппер - Tao Framework (**C#**).

Comment: А ошибки OpenGL вы проверяете? (см. функцию `glGetError`)

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо за долгожданную подсказку. Напишу, как только опробую.

Comment: @Kromster, выдало 1280 (GL_INVALID_ENUM). При проверке выявил, что употребил glShaderSource вместо glShaderSourceARB, но результата не дало.

Comment: Добавьте сделанные изменения в вопрос. Нового кода ошибки после не появилось?

Comment: @Kromster, ничего не изменилось (хотя изменения и не существенные), код такой же

Comment: То есть без шейдера все ок, а с ним - нет. А в чем отличия кроме шейдера? Матрицы Model/View/Projection вы не используете?

Comment: @Kromster, не использовал, хотел упростить до минимума, чтобы была хоть какая-нибудь основа.

Comment: vertexPoc (и vertexPos) - в вершинном шейдере у вас это локальная опечатка, или в самом коде так?